# Xcode errors after installing CocoaPods - no such file or directory

Tags: ios, cordova, cocoapods

I am getting some errors trying to add Pod to my Cordova iOS project

The errors I am seeing in Xcode are :

```
diff: /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

I have tried the following based on information that I have to seem on other Stackoverflow.

1: Close Xcode and run pod install

2: pod update

3: Remove and reinstall cocoa pods

4: create a new project

My project has the structure `/platform/ios` and I am trying to install Firebase. This what I have done to install the pods

1: In the folder above -- pod init
2: edit the podfile and add the firebase
 the podfile content

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'RandstadJobs' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for RandstadJobs
pod 'Firebase/Core'
end
```

3: run pod install

4: open Xcode clean and build

I see the Podfile.lock and the Manifest.lock file. They are in the folder,,

```
/platform/ios/Podfile.lock and /platform/ios/pods/manifest.lock
```

Here is the build phase setting in Xcode

```
diff "${PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH}/Podfile.lock" "${PODS_ROOT}/Manifest.lock" > /dev/null
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
    # print error to STDERR
    echo "error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation." >&2
    exit 1
fi
# This output is used by Xcode 'outputs' to avoid re-running this script phase.
echo "SUCCESS" > "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}"
```

It seems like the path is not getting set.

Can you please give some hints and how to resolve this issue

Thanks

Comment: your pod install went well?

Comment: open terminal and go to the directory containing your xcodeproject file then run pod init command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get pass the error by doing the following:

Add 2 user define variable in Xcode build setting

1: PODS_ROOT  = $(SRCROOT)/PODS

2: PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH = $(SRCROOT)

Then clean the project and compile

Answer (score 0):

You can try clean the folder

> /Users/yourName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData

I just got the problem because I change the project name and folder path.

Comment: Thanks,,, I did .. same issue. Don'r think the path is getting set,, How did you set the PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH

Comment: If you don't mind, email the main code to wshfor@hotmail.com. I check it!

Comment: `PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH = ${SRCROOT}/.` and 
`PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods` in my Pods-App.debug.xcconfig. And it automatically created by `podfile`